# Plot getting replicated using seaborn plot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am writing a script to generate multiple plot figures of GPAs of student in python3. Following is the dataset.

```
Roll No            GPA 1    GPA 2   GPA 3   GPA 4   GPA 5   GPA 6
BE/5746/07          7.82    8.29    8.53    8.76    9.31    8.88
BE/CIVIL/5777/07    7.18    7.29    7.82    8.24    8.94    8.69
BE/CIVIL/5577/07    7.29    7.41    8.18    8.18    8.75    7.63
BE/CIVIL/5753/07    7.29    7.24    7.47    7.65    8.13    8
BE/5782/07          6.88    7.41    7.41    7.59    8.25    7.75
BE/CIVIL/5524/07    6.53    6.82    7.33    7.22    8.06    7.75
BE/5763/07          6.65    6.94    7.35    6.76    8.47    6.94
BE/CIVIL/5780/07    6.82    7.33    7.06    7.06    8.31    6.78
BE/CIVIL/5760/07    6.47    7       6.88    6.39    7.59    6.56
BE/CIVIL/5772/07    6.17    7.06    7.23    6.31    6.76    6.56
BE/CIVIL/5787/07    6.24    6.53    6.35    6.35    7       6.87
BE/CIVIL/5758/07    6.11    6.71    6.47    6.35    7.06    6.25
```

For some minor reason many plots are simply getting copied and I am getting same plots for different rows. I am saving the images with the roll number name removing "/" .The code that I am using is -

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style = "darkgrid")

raw_data = pd.read_csv("student alumni data.csv")

raw_data['img_name'] = raw_data['Roll No'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("/", "") + ".png")
i = 0
plt.ylim(4, 10)

for index, rows in raw_data.iterrows():
    x_list = ['GPA 1', 'GPA 2', 'GPA 3', 'GPA 4', 'GPA 5', 'GPA 6']
    y_list = [rows['GPA 1'], rows['GPA 2'], rows['GPA 3'], rows['GPA 4'], rows['GPA 5'], rows['GPA 6']]

    sns.set(style = "darkgrid")
    sns_plot = sns.barplot(x=x_list, y=y_list, palette="Blues_d").set_title("GPA's of all semesters")
    sns_plot = sns_plot.get_figure()
    sns_plot.savefig("img/" + str(rows['img_name']))
    print("Done fig : ", i)
    del sns_plot, x_list, y_list
    i += 1
```

Please help me out finding the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think that the problem is that the plot is being overwritten each time and they're all getting plotted over each other.

If you change the line:

```
del sns_plot, x_list, y_list
```

To:

```
plt.clf()
```

It should clear out the plot in memory after you have written the image and should give you the desired result.

The `del` line is unnecessary as all of those variables are within scope of the loop so they will be deleted after each iteration of the loop.